Is it possible to default export GPIO devices without writing a custom driver?
We have multiple GPIO controllers where each pin effectively only serves one purpose. For example, if the device-tree entry is the following:
i2c_expander: pca9506@20 {
    compatible = "nxp,pca9505";
    reg = <0x20>;
    gpio-controller;
    #gpio-cells = <2>;
};

Most of these GPIOs are basically just a binary switch. To toggle one of these 'binary switches', we do the following steps:

Export the GPIO device
Set the direction to output
Write values

This seems to be a bit tedious, given that steps 1 and 2 should always happen.
Is the only way to achieve steps 1 and 2 automatically to write a custom kernel driver? It seems to me that there should be some generic driver that does the job for you. Ideally, this "generic driver" exports (for example) GPIO pin 4 under some name with direction out. Is this possible or does one always have to write a custom driver for that?

"we do the following steps: ..." - Such "steps" are for controlling GPIOs from userspace. Directly controlling the hardware from userspace should be considered inferior to a kernel driver. "It seems to me that there should be some generic driver that does the job for you" - Your wish/demand has been granted. Study Documentation/driver-api/gpio/drivers-on-gpio.rst in the kernel source: Note that standard kernel drivers exist for common GPIO tasks and will provide the right in-kernel and userspace APIs/ABIs for the job

@sawdust For example, by abusing the leds-gpio driver!

You appear to be using the deprecated sysfs interface rather than the recommended character device interface.

@IanAbbott I think that’s the way to go (talking about using non-deprecated methods, such as libgpiod for userspace applications). If you want to, you can post that as answer so I can accept it.
